# How to filter data from a stored procedure using when clause or where clause?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-query-builder

Below is my code, I want to fetch data from stored procedure and filter data using where clause but where or when doesn't work with select clause;

```
DB::select('exec my_stored_procedure(?,?)', [$a, $b])
-> where(// condition);   //this is not working
```

Comment: Does the result of `DB::select('exec my_stored_procedure(?,?)', [$a, $b])` return a query builder instance? As you can only use `where` on a Query Builder

Comment: Src: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#where-clauses

Comment: I suggest you build your where conditions into your stored procedure instead :)

Comment: I got result with array by executing stored procedure but what i want to put condition in it. Is there any way to achieve this in laravel? @party-ring

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Where condition in the laravel stored procedure firstly you have to define result set inside your Procedure and for those variable or column names you define inside your procedure's result are used for where conditions from result set.

For procedure use : `Result(Column_name)`

For Laravel use: `DB::select('exec my_stored_procedure(?,?) where Column_name = ?', [$a, $b,$c])`